# Emacs python can not update imported files?

Tags: python, spacemacs, ipython

I am using spacemacs, anaconda-mode.

In file main.py, I imported a class from file a.py. Then I pressed `C-c C-p` to launch an ipython shell, and run main.py, everything is OK. But then I modified the class in a.py, and save, and rerun main.py, I found that the class in a.py was the previous version, which means ipython did not update the content in a.py! Only when I killed the python buffer, and relaunched the ipython shell, did the content in a.py be updated.

I tested this in Spyder, which is a python IDE, and it worked perfect as I expected. But what's wrong with emacs? Are there some configurations that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.

First method:
In ipython console, type

```
%load_ext autoreaload
%autoreload 2
```

Second method:
Create configuration "dev" (or whatever):

```
ipython profile create dev
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'/home/username/.config/ipython/profile_dev/ipython_config.py'
```

And add these lines to "ipython_config.py":

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

Then set variables in Emacs config for python-mode:

```
(setq
   python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
   python-shell-interpreter-args "--profile=dev"
)
```

IPython started with this config will reload modules when you resend code to it.